# Heating a mixture of methanol and water?

Tags: heat, mixtures, process-chemistry

I have a mixture methanol and water, at 25°C, and I want to take it to 250°C. I'll use two heat exchangers: one for taking the mixture from a liquid state (25°C) to a vapor state (X°C), and the second for taking it to the necessary temperature (250°C).

I know that methanol boiling temperature is 64 °C and water boiling temperature is 100°C, and it will be necessary to use two 'kinds' of heat, one for taking the component from 25°C to the boiling temperature, and another called the latent heat, for the phase change.

So, having methanol and water two different values of boiling temperature, what will be the value of X°C, approximately? 100°C, less or more?

Comment: H2O/CH3OH has no azeotrope so boiling points are in the middle between points for pure stuff.

Answer (score 3):

You need to know the composition of your solution and then look at vapor liquid equilibrium data to find the boiling point of your particular composition solution. See [here](http://www.methanol.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Boiling-and-Flash-Points.pdf) for boiling point as a function of composition.